# Get the team backlog using TFS REST API

Tags: rest, tfs

Is there a REST API I can call to retrieve the backlog (as in "the list of work items on the backlog") for a particular team in TFS?

I have found that TFS uses a private API to retrieve the content, but I am not particularly confortable using it since it is not documented.

Btw, the private API in question is

> [project]/[team]/_api/_backlog/payload?__v=5&level=Stories&includeParents=false

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this API on my side, it does get all information on Backlog site. Although it is not documented, you can use it to get information you want.

Comment: Thx, so you do confirm there is no public API I can use, right ?