# TFS 2018 REST API Call for Backlogs // API Version 4.1

Tags: rest, api, tfs, azure-devops

we have TFS 2018 and are able to call the following URL using PAT for authorization:

```
https://our.tfs/tfs/Our.Project.Collection/Our Team Project/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=1234&?api-version=2.0
```

This quite basic call returns expected results.
Trying to request API calls from the following documentation results always in 404 Page not found:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1

For example:

```
https://our.tfs/tfs/Our.ProjectCollection/Our Team Project/_apis/work/backlogs?api-version=4.1
```

which yields the mentioned 404 error.

According Microsoft, the API is supported in version 4.0 on TFS 2018:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/concepts/rest-api-versioning?view=tfs-2018

However, it seems calling the API in version 4.1 in the way the documentation describes it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) only works for VSTS but not for TFS

Do I understand it correctly that any API calls to API version greater than 4.0 are currently only supported by VSTS but not on TFS on prem?
This would mean we have to live with API calls documented in the ["Previous REST API Versions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/overview?view=tfs-2018) when using TFS 2018 on prem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1) format you used is incorrect, you missed the `Team` parameter

The format should be:

```
GET http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/{Project}/{Team}/_apis/work/backlogs?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

It works without any issue on my side.

[image]

Comment: you are completely right! I was only aware of the project collection and the team project. I added the team as well which is the same name as the team project. Then it started working! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will get something by taking a look at these links, see

[Visual Studio Team Services REST API Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

[REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/overview?view=vsts)

I was able to follow this example:

```
https://{instance}[/{collection}[/{team-project}]/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

see what Microsoft speaks about version 4.1 of this doc.

[APIs e uso REST comuns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/overview?view=vsts#common-rest-apis-and-usage)

[Discussion on TFS MS Apis](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/33)

[Similar discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790446/get-the-team-backlog-using-tfs-rest-api)

Hugs

Comment: were you able to run this against your TFS 2018? ..._apis/work/backlogs?api-version=4.1

Comment: Yes and no. some things I usually get, but the backlogs I got as follows ..._api/_backlog/payload?__v=5&level=Stories&includeParents=false
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790446/get-the-team-backlog-using-tfs-rest-api) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/work/backlogs/list?view=vsts-rest-4.1#examples)